# C# finding the nearest and furthest distance from esplanade

Tags: c#

Im trying to find out the nearest and closest distance from esplanade using the latitude and longitude which the formula is :
double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Latitude-s.Latitude,2)+ Math.Pow(Longitude-s.Longitude,2));
I know i need a method to find the esplanade and 2 other methods to find the NearestDist and FurthestDist but i am unsure where to start.

```
public static void FindEsplanade(List<POI>itemList)
    {
        bool
        for (int i =0;i<itemList.Count;i++)
        {
            POI s = itemList[i];
            if (s.Name == "Esplanade")
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public static void NearestDist(List<POI>itemList)
    {

    }

    public static void FurthestDist(List<POI> itemList)
    {

    }
```

Would appreciate some help from my fellow coders!

Here is my class POI which means Point of interest :

```
 class POI
{
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private string name;
    private string address;
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public POI() { }
    public POI (double lat, double longi , string n, string a)
    {
        Latitude = lat;
        Longitude = longi;
        Name = n;
        Address = a;
    }
    public double DistanceFrom(POI s)
    {
        
        double distance = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(Latitude-s.Latitude,2)+ Math.Pow(Longitude-s.Longitude,2));
        return distance;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Latitude: " + Latitude + "Longitude: " + Longitude + "Name: " + Name + "Address: " + Address;
    }
}
```

Sample output of details:
[Output from CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXp6f.png)

Comment: Please post the definition of `POI`.

Comment: @Dai POI is my class, just posted it

Comment: Your `POI` class has numerous bugs in it. For example: your constructor is setting all properties (which is fine) in which case the properties should be immutable (so remove the `set;` keyword), and you don't need backing fields (`private double latitude`) because the properties have that already. Third, you probably should be using the `this.` keyword for readability's sake.

Comment: Just calculate the distances while adding to the distance List varibale and then call sort on that list where the first will be the smallest and the last will be the largest?

Comment: Probably irrelevant to the question, but your formula for the distance is correct only near the equator.

Comment: @KlausGütter They could be writing a game set on Discworld.